What are hotel staff instructed to do when a guest cannot provide a physical bank card to go on file at check in?
I'm not in possession of a physical bank card and will need to check in to several hotels in coming weeks. (my bank's shipping me a new card but their shipping times times are very slow).
I'm curious as to what will happen when I reach the check in counter, the clerk asks for a card to put on file, and I say I don't have one? One guess is they may ask for contactless (mobile) payment (e.g. Apple Pay) instead (which would be fine since I have a digital card on my phone). I believe the limits are smaller than with a physical card so they may not be content with that. It is also possible contactless/mobile doesn't allow for a "hold" to be placed, and a physical card must be used instead (thanks @CMaster for this information).
Curious whether hotel staff ever flatly refuse a guest who cannot provide a physical card to go on file.
Question
What are hotel staff typically trained to do in cases where a guest who has already booked but cannot provide a physical bank card to go on file at check in?

Isn’t this something you should be asking the hotels in question?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

This exact scenario happened to me. Booked a hotel and promptly lost my only credit card. I immediately cancelled my credit card.
Arrived at the hotel, and, of course, they wanted a credit card. I explained the situation. They needed a physical card and would not accept my phone. They even asked for my cancelled card's number, which I explained didn't make any sense.
After a bit of a standoff, the duty manager was summoned, who seemed to dick around a bit on the computer before urging me not to cause any damage to the room and allowing me to check in.
My recommendation is to avoid being in that situation and contact the hotel beforehand to see if it's an issue.

"they even asked for my cancelled card's number" - I wonder if this was just to appease a required field in the hotel's check in software. Or perhaps they were intending to try to use it even though you informed them it was cancelled? (to verify that it was actually cancelled). "and allowed me to checkin" is the most important bit. Guessing the manager may have made a judgement call based on all available information, probably including your demeanour, appearance, and likely purpose of the stay (to figure out if you were the kind of person who may trash the room and not pay).

@stevec Also I booked through a booking service, they likely could see I had a large number of bookings that didn't have an issue.

This is an extremely helpful answer because it details what hotel staff really did in practice. I think it should be taken with a grain of salt purely because the sample size is small (would be interesting to hear from, say, 10 or more people who had encountered this situation - if they all report the same thing happening I'd guess checkin might be more of a hassle but ultimately fine most of the time).

For various reasons I have a similar situation sometimes with car rentals. They need a CC on file, what I can offer does not work due to various restrictions on their end, there is a lot of dicking around until finally it is decided that what I have is good enough. I think it's important to remember that nobody is helped with the hotel (or car rental) refusing service to you, so staff tends to try hard to avoid this.

Was it in Vietnam? My experience was that they often don't even ask for the card, so long as the booking was done online. What price range was your hotel in?

@xLeitix Car rentals are known to require additional 100% insurance without a credit card at hand. (e.g., when having only a debit card)

@VladimirFГероямслава: I once booked a rental car through a travel-benefits-card company which offered as a membership perk that they could book a rental car without needing a credit card (I had debit cards).  When I got to the airport, the clerk at the desk explained that although the travel card company allowed me to book without a credit card, that didn't mean I'd be able to actually rent the car without one.  Fortunately, there was a bus that could take me close to where I needed to go.

@stevec Yes, that sounds very plausible. It's like Jeanne Robertson's classic "We Don't Sell Vanilla Milkshakes" piece. "You can't make that stuff uup."

Regarding them asking for the canceled card number, the bank will usually issue the new card with the old number, just an updated cvv. It's reasonably likely the hotel could get a charge through either without a cvv or possibly with the old one as stored at booking—I know some issuers let those go through for subscriptions on an expired card, not sure if in other cases.

Car rentals used to accept cash deposits, but in that case there is well-defined insurance for any loss, up to and including the car disappearing (and the insurance is at the customer's expense).

This is going to depend entirely on the hotel, so you should call up and ask.
Some will happily accept Google/Apple Pay, others will insist on a physical plastic card. Cash deposits are still an option in some places, especially cheaper ones, but many places will rather refuse your custom entirely.
If you plan on traveling regularly, it's worth getting two bank cards/credit cards from separate banks and storing them in different places when you travel, which minimizes the risk of running into problems like this if one of them is stolen/blocked/lost etc.

Cash deposits are often an option, but it no doubt depends on the location (country as well as hotel). E.g I had a new CC last month and didn't have the letter with the PIN yet so couldn't use it, mentioned this at a Marriott and they gladly took a cash deposit.

Or get a credit card such as AmEx that promises to deliver a replacement quickly; and/or insurance with a good telephone help/concierge service. But yes you don't want to be stuck without a card.

This can vary widely from one hotel to the next, so the only way to know is to call each one of them. It also depends on how you booked (pre-paid/post-paid), if the hotel offers any kind of extras (calls, Internet, mini-bar, bars and restaurants, spa...) which could be charged to the room or not.
If the booking is pre-paid, the guarantee is only for the extras charged to the room.
Possibilities include:

They don't have any extras whatsovever: no guarantee needed
They have extras, but can block them (block the mini-bar, provide the room without one, or with an empty one, and not allow charges to the room): no guarantee needed
They have extras and somehow can't block them: they will need a guarantee. They may be able to use your card in Apple Pay as a deposit. They may ask for an actual payment (to be refunded, less charges, at the end of your stay), either using a (virtual) card or in cash.

Depending on how you booked (especially whether there was some kind of 3-D Secure check or not), they may want to see the card used for the payment for security purposes (quite different from taking a deposit). No idea what they would do in this case since it's already been charged.
If you didn't pay in advance, the most likely thing is that they'll ask for you to pay for the room in advance (full stay or day-to-day), either using the card in your mobile or using cash (or other means).
Additional notes:

If you make a payment in any form to act as a deposit, make sure you get a receipt, and that it says refundable deposit or something similar, and the amount.
While most places will accept cash, I believe we've seen stories around here about hotels not accepting cash and insisting on a card.

As you see, lots of situations, so ask the hotel, referencing your specific booking.
Also, if your bank is so slow, any chance you could get a card quicker via Revolut for instance, or some other neobank providing cards quickly or immediately?

In my experience all hotels (at least in the US) require a deposit regardless of in-room services: it's there to cover or at least disincentivize damages to your room.

@lambshaanxy I've only seen it in US hotels, but my travel experience might be limited.

@lambshaanxy You mustn't be staying at some of the hotels I've been staying at then in the US.  The cheap assed ones I've been using in the middle of nowhere don't require a deposit.

These days budget chain hotels often have automated check-in where you don't even see a person let alone have to show a card; although some will require you to give a credit card in advance that may be charged for extras. Particularly with the rise in accommodation that doesn't have a traditional front-of-house. But it does vary a lot.

Last time I visited a hotel in the USA without a working plastic credit card, check-in worked like this: the receptionist wanted to reserve a deposit on a card, using a plastic card in their card reader. I was able to provide a card which worked for that, and they didn't mind that it wasn't a credit card. I was prepared for this, so just before my trip I topped up my card so that there was enough funds for the deposit (a few hundred USD). They released the deposit a few days after I left.

Cash
Not quite your scenario but similar.  My wife booked us a room in a Holiday Inn Express in Bangkok but, due to a change of plans, she could not come so I checked in alone.  They asked for her credit card but I explained that she was not coming.  I could have provided one but they asked for a cash deposit of 1000THB (23GBP / 30USD / 27EUR).  They put my note in an envelope and gave me a receipt.  When I checked out, they gave me the envelope.  They did not check the room.

If you find old American Express commercials (for their non-credit card payment card products, from, I'm guessing, the 1970s), this was a scenario  that they said they could handle. In a typical commercial, one spouse would lose a wallet, there'd be joint panic, and then the hotel person would say "was it American Express?" and everything would work out.
I've done exactly what would happened in the ad (lost my wallet at the start of a trip). Other than the car rental company refusing to believe that I had a driver's license, it worked out (it was a business trip - a coworker rented the car).
Talk to the credit card company. You've reported the issue to them and you are their customer. Have them work things out with the hotel. Don't expect a "smooth as silk" process, but I'd expect success.

American Express should still do something similar (e.g. speaking to the hotel), but they typically provide a replacement card very quickly, so I'm guessing the OP isn't with them. Other providers typically don't give the same service, but if you lose your card on a trip good-quality travel insurance might help (the sort that comes with lots of extras, helplines, etc).
